# Using multiple indexers with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have been trying to use Moq to fake an object set (and get) with multiple indexers.  I have previously been using Moq with single indexers for quite some time, but it doesn't seem to be working using multiple indexers.  I am aware from my research that Moq can have a problem using It.IsAny<> for indexer parameters, but I have also tried the following code with specific parameters (like mock[1, "BlockItem"])  Here is my code:

```
m_storageAccessor.SetupSet(
mock => mock[It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()] = It.IsAny<object>()).Callback(
                (int i, string s, object o) =>
                       {
                           m_storageAccessor.SetupGet(
                               mock => mock[i, s]).Returns(
                                   () => { return o; });
                       });
```

This generates the following exception, again, no matter what parameters I give the indexer function in SetupSet().

> Initialization method UnitTest.BonusHandlerTest.MyTestInitialize threw
>   exception. System.ArgumentNullException: 
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   arguments.
>
> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodInfo
>   method, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateCallArgs(Expression
>   instance, MethodInfo method, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance,
>   MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance,
>   MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments) TCall](Mock`1 mock,
>   Action`1 setterExpression, Func`5 callFactory) b__25()
>   Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T](Func`1 function)
>   Moq.Mock.SetupSet[T](Mock`1 mock, Action`1 setterExpression, Func`1
>   condition) SetupSet(Action`1 setterExpression)
>   UnitTest.BonusHandlerTest.SetupPersistence() in
>   C:\perforce\dev\KHIRST_Client12.BonusHandler\Client12\Gaming\BonusHandler\UnitTest\BonusHandlerTest.cs:
>   line 868 UnitTest.BonusHandlerTest.MyTestInitialize() in
>   C:\perforce\dev\KHIRST_Client12.BonusHandler\Client12\Gaming\BonusHandler\UnitTest\BonusHandlerTest.cs:
>   line 100

It almost seems like, based on what I have tried, that Moq is unable to do indexers with multiple parameters.  Anyone have any ideas?  The interwebs haven't been much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I set this scenario up and there were no exceptions:

```
        var myStub = new Mock<Foo>();
        myStub.SetupSet(foo => foo[12, "asdf"] = null).Callback((int i, string s, object o) => myStub.SetupGet(foo => foo[i, s]).Returns(o));
```

It appears that it doesn't just like the It.IsAny<> for the parameters to the indexer, but also to the set value.  I've never tried to do this in my testing, but this seems like a current limitation of the tool to me.

Comment: Thanks, Erik, for verifying that.  Looks like I will have to go with an old fashioned test component for this one.